# Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol when constructing an angular 6 library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library, angular-cli-v6

I'm getting the following error while performing 'ng build' from my library.

I'm using Angular 6 at the moment, but I believe this error is not version related.

> /home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/projects/pf-siseg/src/lib/keycloak-service/keycloak.service.ts:13:1:
>   Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol
>   'KeycloakService':
>   /home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/projects/pf-siseg/src/lib/keycloak-service/keycloak.service.ts:18:12:
>   Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime:
>   Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the
>   value of this variable is needed by the template compiler.
>   {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Variable not
>   initialized","line":17,"character":11} Error:
>   /home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/projects/pf-siseg/src/lib/keycloak-service/keycloak.service.ts:13:1:
>   Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol
>   'KeycloakService':
>   /home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/projects/pf-siseg/src/lib/keycloak-service/keycloak.service.ts:18:12:
>   Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime:
>   Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the
>   value of this variable is needed by the template compiler.
>   {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Variable not
>   initialized","line":17,"character":11}
>       at /home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.js:707:31
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at validateMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.js:695:46)
>       at MetadataCollector.getMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.js:550:21)
>       at MetadataCache.getMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/metadata_cache.js:86:41)
>       at Object.getSourceFileMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/compiler_host.js:112:56)
>       at Object.readMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/metadata_reader.js:46:37)
>       at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.getMetadataFor (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/compiler_host.js:464:38)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/static_symbol_resolver.js:480:49)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/home/rafaelvicio/desenv/my-lib/arquitetura-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/static_symbol_resolver.js:268:33)

keycloak.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakLoginOptions } from './keycloak.d';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import * as Keycloak from './keycloak';

export type KeycloakClient = Keycloak.KeycloakInstance;
type InitOptions = Keycloak.KeycloakInitOptions;

@Injectable()
export class KeycloakService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    static keycloakAuth: KeycloakClient;

.... More code here
```

Answer (score 34):

add `// @dynamic` before the class that declares static methods

Comment: would be good to hear why this resolves the problem

Comment: For me, it had to do with `static` methods. Adding `// @dynamic` solves it.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue today in an `util` class providing static methods as helpers.

I solved it by replacing `this` with `ObjectUtils` (the class name itself), and it works.

Also as @NicolasThierion mentioned in his [reply](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18867#issuecomment-357484102) commented by @stack247, you could also try the following hack

```
// @dynamic
export class SomeClass {
    public static get() { return 'someValue'; } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Angular V8 and had the same problem. Angular does not allow a static variable to not be initialized. The solution was to initialize with null to avoid errors.

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

    static URL: string = null;
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the "variable" it points to is a getter function!

Comment: Thanks, it's work. Just add default value, maybe null.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this was using a static value incorrectly in the constructor in a method. Referring to the static value by `this.STATIC_VALUE` rather than `Foo.STATIC_VALUE`.

```
class Foo {
  static STATIC_VALUE = 'hi';

  constructor(
    private bar: string
  ) {}

  static defoo(): Foo {
    return Foo(this.STATIC_VALUE);
  }
}
```

The method defoo should have been

```
  static defoo(): Foo {
    return Foo(Foo.STATIC_VALUE);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and resolved the problem by removing 'static' from the variable.

Comment: Removing `static` fundamentally changes the nature of how/where you use the variable.